# Text input margins in Firefox

Tags: css

I am having problems with the text input in firefox, it has some margins and I can;t get rid of them, maybe that space is not a margin?(it is outside the border of the input so it looks like a margin).

[image]

In the image above the width of the input is set to 100%,,margin and padding is 0, also i tried setting  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

I would like some resources or an explanation to make me understand what is  that space and how can I get rid of it?
Thanks.

Edit1:
Here is my current test page
https://www.designersbookshop.com/support/test.html
also i made a copy in ...test_2.html (i will try the suggestions on the test.html),
Check the inputs on left side.

Edit2:
My Firefox version is 10.0.2
Here is how an input element looks like in firebug, it is clear that a margin or something similar is painted outside the border(or i am stupid but I want to learn)
[image: view with firebug]
in the image above the border of the input is the small line(1px) visible on left and right of the input.

Edit3 I figure it out, is the border, I am on Ubuntu but I has similar on Mac,so it is the theme engine that adds that white border?

Comment: Something may be overriding your declaration there. Try `margin: 0 !important;` and `padding: 0 !important;`

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate your error?

Comment: Which version of firefox are you using? I can't see the problem here

Answer (score 1):

May be it is `outline` or `border`

Try

```
input {
   padding:0;
   margin: 0;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
}
```

**Update:** I cannot duplicate your problem on my system. This is what i see

[image]

Comment: I do not want to remove the border since then you  can't see the input if it has a white background (currently in the image is black  but by default it will be white,uses user theme)

Comment: @simion314, it will be easier if you show me the problem rather than describe. It might not take more than 5 mins to solve it, otherwise hours or even days. Try to duplicate problem in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sure I edited the question, try in firebug and see the space outside of the border, i want to make the input fir inside it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

You're using OSX right? I think what you are referring to is the focus highlighting. It's only seen on the active element, right?

Normally that is controlled by

```
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Some people use it to remove the rectangle around links as well. which is a bad practice since it reduces usability as users can't visually see what is the active link. (think of keyboard users.)

FYI: here is a screenshot of your test page (from Edit1) in Firefox 10 under Windows: http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/1764/inputform.png

As it always has been with input fields in HTML - their appearance is often dictated by the OS or browser. Very hard to get a consistent appearance.

Comment: thx, i your image helped me in my search, that white space was in fact the border.